# Can "plan work" be used in a slogan?

Tags: grammar, slogan

I would like to use the slogan "Plan work. Track time." for a product I'm working on. However, I'm a bit alarmed by the fact I get virtually no search results on Google for "plan work", which gives me the impression it's not proper English. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, "plan work" is grammatically correct.  As a native speaker, I also understand perfectly what you are trying to get at. It's just a command.  If in doubt, consider the sentence "I plan work."

Furthermore, since "plan work" doesn't show up with much in Google, that might make it a perfect slogan for your product.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be pedantic, you *can* do what you please. Perhaps the question may better be phrased *is it clear (given some context) what I'm trying to say?*. You could also borrow a leaf from Steve Jobs and get away with something as grammatically incorrect as *Think Different*. No license required.

Comment: Gotta say, you're so funny!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "plan work" is grammatically correct. But it doesn't *feel* right.  How about "Plan your work. Track your time." ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the subject is your software, rather than "you". To emphasize this idea, how about "Plans your work. Tracks your time."?